# Received-Spf: neutral

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, spf

I have an Ubuntu-server with Wordpress installed. When sending out emails from the server I get the following header:

```
Received-Spf: neutral.
```

I did set the SPF-record in the following matter:

```
v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com include:spf.gigahost.dk ~all
```

The a-record resolves to the IP of my server which is

```
46.101.199.65
```

When testing with http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester with the IP and email hello@kjottogblod.com it passes.

Any idea why Google is not marking emails send from the server as "pass"?

This is the complete header. I've replaced my email with xxx@xxx.com. But the receiving email is a Google Apps account.

```
Delivered-To: xxx@xxx.com
Received: by 10.157.38.140 with SMTP id l12csp352662otb;
        Tue, 5 Jul 2016 06:42:16 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.28.50.131 with SMTP id y125mr17192051wmy.94.1467726136065;
        Tue, 05 Jul 2016 06:42:16 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk>
Received: from ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk ([46.101.199.65])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id f66si16033wme.56.2016.07.05.06.42.15
        for <xxx@xxx.com>;
        Tue, 05 Jul 2016 06:42:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 46.101.199.65 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk) client-ip=46.101.199.65;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 46.101.199.65 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk
Received: by ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id AF06414471B; Tue,  5 Jul 2016 09:42:15 -0400 (EDT)
To: xxx@xxx.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Your_Kj=C3=B8tt_og_Blod_order_receipt_from_July_5,_2016?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:class-phpmailer.php
Date: Tue, 5 Jul 2016 13:42:15 +0000
From: =?UTF-8?Q?Kj=C3=B8tt_og_Blod?= <hello@kjottogblod.com>
Message-ID: <9e947b8b46848b4f9fb10ff2e25ee2a1@kjottogblod.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with this line: 

Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 46.101.199.65 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk

But the domain is kjottogblod.com. The above is the droplet name on Digital Ocean. How are they related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `smtp.mailfrom` address that is used in the SPF check. This is the so-called envelope sender. And since ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01-tpk is not a valid domain it can not have a SPF record, hence the Neutral result.

So you will have to set up your Wordpress installation to use a better envelope-sender. I'm no Wordpress expert, but it seems that there are several filters/plugins that allow you to change the mail settings.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. Instead of using the server to send out emails, I am now using Mailjet. Works perfect, and the server now has both SPF and DKIM records, and mails are passed through. Thanks again.